# Find a basis of this vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

> 5. Find a basis for space $V$ where 
>      $$ V = \{ p\in P_6 : p=ax^6 - bx^5 + ax^4 - cx^3 + (a+b+c)x^2 - (a-c)x + (3a-2b+16c) \} $$
>      where $a,b$ and $c$ are any real numbers.

Please give the complete answer as I have no clue how to find basis of this type of spaces.

Comment: There is no such thing as "**the** basis" of a vector space  (unless $V=0$).

Comment: Hint:  Letting the linear parameters $a,b,c$ be (by turns) $1$ and the rest zero will give you one basis.  Other bases are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=0$ to get a first basis vector (polynomial). Then take $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=0$ to get a second basis vector. Lastly take $a=0$, $b=0$, $c=1$ to get a third basis vector.

Alternatively and better, note that
$$p = ax^6 - bx^5 + ax^4 + cx^3 + (a+b+c)x^2 - (a-c)x + (3a-2b+16c) \\
= a(x^6+x^4+x^2-x+3) + b(-x^5+x^2-2) + c(x^3+x^2+x+16)$$
and identify three basis vectors from this.